# How to run Bully : Scholarship Edition?

Tags: wine, games

Can someone give a step-by-step tutorial on how to run it under wine ?

Comment: I don't think this game is running well enough under Linux to be actually playable, check http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8581

Comment: (It is possible to play the game)

How do you want to install the game Alaukik?

Comment: @Bruno Pereira What do you mean?

Comment: you can install it directly from a media (cd) or via steam. which are you using?

Comment: @BrunoPereira DVD version

Comment: ok, going to download and test.

Comment: On `wine` the game runs but only the backgrounds show up. The weirdest thing is I bought the game on steam for testing and that thing runs flawless there. I will have a look on how to make the steam and the DVD version run similar, just havent been having a lot of time this weekend. Maybe tonight. Well make you game run!!! :D

Comment: @BrunoPereira You know Bully has some problems running on windows too . Try the v1.2 patch.

Comment: Yeah, I am assuming that steam already has it updated. I will try tonight and let you know how it works.

Comment: @BrunoPereira Did you try it?

Comment: @Alaukik working on it (sorry man, busy week!). So far pure wine fails hard everywhere, got my hands on a copy of the game for Steam and I am installing it at the moment. Also trying the solution bellow with different variables, so far fail hard has hell (read comments on solution).

Comment: @BrunoPereira This person got it to work on mac with wine (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RySQjPJvcQ) .

Answer (score 1):

This game doesn't run well in Wine, but you can play it in Ubuntu by using a virtual machine. You can create a virtual machine by using Virtualbox by following these steps:
First, obtain a physical disk of Windows or an .iso

Next, install VirtualBox. You can do so from the Software Center. Once Virtualbox has finished installing, open it.
[image]

Click "New" in the toolbar. In the wizard that appears, click "Next". Name the virual machine and click "Next". Set the memory size to half your ram. Click Next. Make a new virtual hard disk for the VM, I would recommend around 40 gb. 
[image]
Finish the wizard by clicking "Create". Double-click the virtual machine in the list in the VirtualBox main window. In the first run wizard, navigate to the iso you downloaded earlier, or select "Use Physical Drive". Follow the on-screen instructions to install Windows.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote.

Comment: I'm reversing the downvote, since no explanation was given and this answer seems quite reasonable.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know of any other way to solve this guy's problem.

Comment: (Did not downvote or upvote so I have no clue but) this game requires hardware shader 3 support and its crazy hard to run nicely even in native Windows, lets say I did 3 installs on Windows7 vboxes and every time I tried to run the game ended up having to re-install or cd repair the system (would not even boot on safe mode). That can be a reason. Also, having Windows is not an options for all of the users, I sort of understand that some users will say "I need to buy a copy of Windows and install it on a vbox to be able to run this???".